# Combinatorics: "four male-female couples and eight chairs" problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I was trying to solve the following problem:

> Eight persons, consisting of four male-female couples, are to be seated in a row of eight chairs. How many seating arrangements are there in each of the following cases:
>
> 1. There are no other restrictions.
> 2. The men must sit together and the women must sit together.
> 3. The men must sit together.
> 4. Each couple must sit together.

For the first and forth points I was able to find a solution easily (respectively $10*9*8$ and $8*6*4*2$), but for the other middle points I am having some little troubles. Doesn't the 3rd point imply the second?

In both cases, the first person will have $8$ places to choose from, but the second person that seats will have to be careful depending on the first person was a male or a female and depending if it is a male or a female.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. $8!$, on first chair can seat 8 different people, on 2nd 7, $\dots$
2. There are two options: $MMMMFFFF$ or $FFFFMMMM$. Either way there are $4!$ possibilities to arrange males, the same goes for females. Total $2\cdot 4! \cdot 4!$.
3. Similarily as in 2., but there are 5 ways to put all the man together, and $4!$ ways to arrange them in a group (same for females), so $5 \cdot 4! \cdot 4!$.
4. $4! * 2^4 $, $4$ couples, each couple takes 2 chairs, 2 ways to arrange each couple.

Comment: MMMMFFFF FMMMMFFF FFMMMMFF FFFMMMMF FFFFMMMM

Comment: You're welcome:)

Comment: You should be able to do it by yourself. You need to answer 3 questions: 1) What are the possibilities of putting $m$ males together in a $n$-chaired line. 2) What are the possibitlies of arranging them in a group? 3) What are the possibilities to arrange $n-m$ females on all the remaining seats?

Comment: It is certainly ok.